# Calls the wrong method if some but not all optional parameters are provided

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have two action methods for the same page, one using GET for initial load and one using POST for the form submit which should redirect to another page. Both calls require one mandatory parameter in the url and can also take two optional parameters from the query string.

Lets call the optional parameters `oPar1` and `oPar2` which are picked up as parameters on the GET method just fine in any combination. These are added to the ViewModel used by the page.

The POST needs to provide the parameters to the action method so in the `action` attribute of the form tag we have:

```
@Url.Action("PostAction", new { mPar = Model.mPar, oPar1 = Model.oPar1, oPar2 = Model.oPar2 })
```

Needless to say the method is also set to `post`.

The problem comes when I provide only one of the two optional parameters in the GET. When the submit button is pressed the GET method seems to be called and not the POST. If I provide both optional parameters or none at all then the POST is called fine and I get the parameters as expected.

The function declarations are:

```
[HttpGet]
[RequireHttps]
public ActionResult GetAction(string mPar, string oPar1, string oPar2)
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
[RequireHttps]
public ActionResult PostAction(string mPar, MyModel model, string oPar1, string oPar2)
```

The routes are:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "GetActionRoute",
    "mycontroller/{mPar}/pageName",
    new { controller = "myController", action = "GetAction", mPar = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") });

routes.MapRoute(
    "PostActionRoute",
    "mycontroller/{mPar}/pageName",
    new { controller = "myController", action = "PostAction", mPar = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") });
```

It's worth adding that this setup worked until I added oPar2 to the mix. Am I doing something really dumb here?

Comment: What you're describing, simply, is not possible. If you were talking about two GET actions or two POST actions, maybe, but the fact that they are GET and POST actions is enough to distinguish them from each other. If the URL is requested via GET, you'll get the GET action; if by POST, you'll get the POST action. If you're requesting via POST and you get the GET action, there's something wrong at a fundamental level with the framework itself.

Comment: Well I'm glad it's not just me that thinks this is a bit crazy...

Answer (score 0):

You don't change your optional parameters so why do you need to pass them?

If you absolutely need this you can add those two properties properties (`oPar1` and `oPar2`) in your view-model and display them in the form as hidden.

Then in your `POST` action you use your view-model as a parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
[RequireHttps]
public ActionResult PostAction(YourViewModel yourViewModel)
```

By doing this you don't need to add an extra route for your `POST` requests (because it will match the default ASP.Net MVC route).

In case you did this to keep a clean URL and SEO-friendly URL for your `POST` request keep in mind that those URLs will never be displayed, that's called from a `form` submission and then can use the default route.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that clearer. I am using a form element with a defined `action` and an input element to submit.

Comment: From your new answer I realise I may be complicating things by having the parameters remain in the query string. Adding them to the model sounds like a good idea. I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: You can look at how ASP.Net generates the views when you create a new Controller using Entity Framework CRUD.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the solution but I didn't provide enough information in the question for others to answer it. Sorry about that.

The ViewModel being passed to the page during the GET was using a `Uri` object and not a string to represent `oPar1`. The action attribute was still as it was written, so the object being passed to the POST was a `Uri` and not a `string`. Understandably the binder was not converting the `Uri` to a `string` automatically. Converting the model to use a string instead of a Uri object made everything work nice again.

Having said this it's still a little weird that the GET method was being called instead of the POST. I would have thought that if one of the optional parameters was of the wrong format that it would be ignored. I'd be interested to know if anyone else could confirm this behaviour.

Thanks to everyone else who commented.